# Update of SSRS DataSets Data

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I generated a report using a table 't' which has two columns ID,Name I generated a Report which displays the Table t Using SSRS My problem is After generation of report i have inserted one more record into table t but the new record which i have inserted is not viewed in the report , how to update the datasets data so that it reflects new changes in table t

Comment: Delete the dataset and recreate new one. Always worked for me.

Comment: Are you using VS2012 or VS2008? Does the report show any data or is it showing blank screen?

Comment: @Pratik Kaje , Now its working fine thank you for ur comment it helped me